# Listen to an AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is it possible for a Java Lambda client app to "listen" to a result of a lambda? For example, the client app isn't going to invoke the lambda but say the lambda is triggered from an SNS topic. I want the client app to be able to get the result of the lambda that was triggered by the SNS. I couldn't find anything in documentations to see if this was possible or not.

Answer (score 2):

The Lambda client for Java is a part of the AWS SDK for Java. It enables you to call the AWS Lambda API from your Java code, and that's it.
This means that you can run from your Java code roughly the same operations as you normally would from the AWS CLI (create / edit / delete / invoke a function etc.).

I am not aware of an ability to bind to a Lambda function and listen for a response (in general, regardless of the Java client).

What you *could* probably do is make the Lambda function publish to SNS when it's done running and subscribe to the relevant topic from the Java client, or make SNS notify your client app over HTTP.

Comment: This or write the result into a sqs queue which then can be consumed by your app